# Sublime Text: Keyword Highlight for Ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I'm using sublime text 2 to code ruby.

Is there a way to highlight the keyword pairs(do...end) which is similar to the parentheses match mode?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new [Bracket Highlighter 2 alpha branch](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9756).  I believe you can now customize it to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Sublime extension called BracketHighlighter ([github](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter)). If it doesn't support Ruby, it should be easy to add - the logic is already there, you just need to add the 'brackets'.

Comment: Thanks. But no luck. It could not show me the pairs like do..do...end..end.